# Compilation error with promise

Tags: typescript

When I compile this file I get the following error:

> 44:16 - error TS2693: 'Promise' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.

```
fighter.ts:44:14 - error TS2693: 'Promise' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.

44   return new Promise((resolve) => {
```

How can I describe the `Promise` correctly in this case?

```
export interface IFighter {
    _name: string;
    _health: number;
    _power: number;
    health: () => number;
    name: () => string;
    setDamage: (damage: number) => void;
    hit: (enemy: Fighter, point: number) => void;
    knockout: () => Promise<Promise<any>>;


}


export class Fighter implements IFighter { 
    _name: string;
    _health: number;
    _power: number;
  constructor(name: string, health: number, power: number) {
    this._name = name;
    this._health = health;
    this._power = power;
  }

  health(): number {
    return this._health;
  }

  name(): string {
    return this._name;
  }

  setDamage(damage: number): void {
    this._health = this._health - damage;
    console.log(`${this._name} got ${damage} dmg. ${this._health}hp less`);
  }

  hit(enemy: Fighter, point: number): void {
    let damage: number = point * this._power;
    enemy.setDamage(damage);
  }

  knockout(): Promise<any> {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      console.log("time is over");
      setTimeout(() => {
        resolve((): void => {});
      }, 500);
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Please post error messages **as text**, not as a *picture* of text (or at least in addition to the picture). Why: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/157247

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error you are specifically getting is probably due to the fact that you are targeting `es5`. `es5` does not have promises built-in. There is a promise type, but not a promise constructor defined in the `es5` typescript lib. If your runtime has the `Promise` constructor, or you have a polyfill for it, you can add a `lib` attribute to your `tsconfig.json` to tell typescript to add the definitions for promises (the full `es2015` conforming promise).

```
{
    ....
    "lib": ["es5","es2015.promise","dom", "scripthost"] 
    ....
}
```

**Edit** As @Oleksii points out `knockout: () => Promise<Promise<any>>;` should be `knockout: () => Promise<any>` but that is not specially related to the error in the question.;

Comment: @titian-cernicova-dragomirmy config file has `"target": "es6"`, but i anyway add your `lib` answer and still get the same error

Comment: @tranntus This is the common reason the error. How are you building your project ? Are you sure the tsconfig.json you edited is getting picked up ? (check the output to see if teh generated js conatins arraow functions or classes as if shoudl it you compile to es2015, or were these features were downcompiled to simple functions as they would be if you target es5)

Answer (score 2):

change you in your `IFighter` interface:

this one `knockout: () => Promise<Promise<any>>;`

to `knockout: () => Promise<any>;`

It makes no sense to write `Promise<Promise<Promise<...<T>>>>` because anyway it will be represented as `Promise<T>`